# Adding an index to mongodb collection hash field with dynamic key values

Tags: dynamic, hash, indexing, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4

I m using mongoid and rails 4. I have a model that has a 'data' field of type hash. The field would store dynamic key value pairs. I know that we can add indexing to the static fields but is it possible to add indexing to the keys of 'data' and how should it be done.

Comment: As a general guideline it is always better to have constant keys. Instead of having a hash field with dynamic keys, I would almost always prefer having an array of hashes. That is `[{key: dynamic_key1, value: value1}, {key: dynamic_key2, value: value2}]` is better than `{dynamic_key1: value1, dynamic_key2: value2}` if you need indexes and want to have more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add in the same way you would if the index were not in a dynamic field,
something like this:

```
class Person
  field :data, type: Hash
  index('data.foo' => 1)
end
```

I am pretty much sure Mongoid dont validate if the fields exists, so you can create any index on your model. Also if you dont have all docs containing the field, I would also add the `sparse` option to the index, so you save some space in memory.

Comment: at run time, how m i supposed to know that one of the keys would be 'foo'. 100 different users might send 100 different key-value pairs.

Comment: i see, so if you dont know the key, you wont be able to create a index, thats how mongodb works by design.